# Angular 6 Material Tree view

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I'm using Angular Material v6. I'm trying to create a tree dynamically from a JSON file on a server. Currently, the tree can create a parent but it does not create children. The console correctly outputs the parent and children. However, I can't seem to find the source of this issue.

Here's my code:

**testcasefolder-list.component.html:**

```html
<mat-tree [dataSource]="nestedDataSource" [treeControl]="nestedTreeControl" class="example-tree">
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle>
    <li class="mat-tree-node">
      <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
      {{node.category.name}}
    </li>
  </mat-tree-node>

  <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasNestedChild">
    <li>
      <div class="mat-tree-node">
        <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle
                [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.filename">
          <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
            {{nestedTreeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
          </mat-icon>
        </button>
        {{node.category.name}}
      </div>
      <ul [class.example-tree-invisible]="!nestedTreeControl.isExpanded(node)">
        <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </mat-nested-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

**testcasefolder-list.component.ts:**

```ts
import { TestcasefolderService } from './../../services/testcasefolder-service';
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { NestedTreeControl } from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import { MatTreeNestedDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { ITestcasefolder } from '../../model/itestcasefolder';
export class CategoryNode {
  children: CategoryNode[ ];
  category: ITestcasefolder;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-testcasefolder-list',
  templateUrl: './testcasefolder-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./testcasefolder-list.component.css']
})
export class TestcasefolderListComponent implements OnInit {
// Does not follow main/sub category - just has a simple category!
@Input() categoryID: number;
@Output() categoryIDChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

nestedTreeControl: NestedTreeControl<CategoryNode>;
nestedDataSource: MatTreeNestedDataSource<CategoryNode>;
type: any;
hasNestedChild = (_: number, nodeData) => !(nodeData.type);

constructor(
  private dataBrokerService: TestcasefolderService
) {
  this.nestedTreeControl = new NestedTreeControl(node => of(node.children));
  this.nestedDataSource = new MatTreeNestedDataSource();
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.dataBrokerService.getTestcasefolders().subscribe(categories => this.nestedDataSource.data = this.buildTree(categories));
}

onChange() {
  this.categoryIDChange.emit(this.categoryID);
}

private buildTree(categories: ITestcasefolder[]): CategoryNode[] {

  const tree: CategoryNode[] = [];
  const map: {[s: number]: CategoryNode} = {};

  // Build an index of the nodes
  categories.forEach(cat => {
    map[cat.id] = {children: [], category: cat};
  });
  console.log(tree);
  // Start adding nodes to tree
  for (const key of Object.keys(map)) {
    const catNode = map[+key];

    if (map[catNode.category.parentid]) {
      // Add it to the parent
      map[catNode.category.parentid].children.push(catNode);
    } else {
      // Add it to root
      tree.push(catNode);
    }
  }
  console.log(tree);
  return tree;
}

}
```

**testcasefolder-service.ts:**

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { MessageService } from './message-service.service';
import { ITestcasefolder } from '../model/itestcasefolder';
import { Global } from '../shared/Global';


const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestcasefolderService {

  private testcasefolderServiceUrl = Global.BASE_USER_ENDPOINT +  'testcasefolders';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private messageService: MessageService) { }

  private log(message: string) {
    this.messageService.add(`TestcasefolderService: ${message}`);
  }


  getTestcasefolders(): Observable<ITestcasefolder[]> {
  return this.http.get<ITestcasefolder[]>(this.testcasefolderServiceUrl)
    .pipe(
      tap(requirements => this.log('fetched testcasefolder')),
      catchError(this.handleError('getTestcasefolders', []))
    );
 }

 getTestcasefolder(id: string): Observable<ITestcasefolder> {
  const url = `${this.testcasefolderServiceUrl}/${id}`;
  return this.http.get<ITestcasefolder>(url).pipe(
    tap(_ => this.log(`fetched testcasefolder id=${id}`)),
    catchError(this.handleError<ITestcasefolder>(`get testcasefolder id=${id}`))
  );
 }

addTestcasefolder(testcasefolder: ITestcasefolder): Observable<ITestcasefolder> {
delete testcasefolder['id'];
 return this.http.post<ITestcasefolder>(this.testcasefolderServiceUrl, testcasefolder, httpOptions)
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
.pipe(tap((testcasefolder: ITestcasefolder) => this.log(`added testcasefolder w/ id= ${testcasefolder.id}`)),
catchError(this.handleError<ITestcasefolder>('addTestcasefolder'))
);
}

updateTestcasefolder(testcasefolder: ITestcasefolder): Observable<any> {
  const url = `${this.testcasefolderServiceUrl}/${testcasefolder.id}`;
  return this.http.put(url, testcasefolder, httpOptions)
  .pipe(tap(_ => this.log(`updated testcasefolder id=${testcasefolder.id}`)),
  catchError(this.handleError<any>('updateTestcasefolder')));
}
deleteTestcasefolder(testcasefolder: ITestcasefolder |  string ): Observable<ITestcasefolder> {
const id = typeof testcasefolder === 'string' ? testcasefolder : testcasefolder.id;
const url = `${this.testcasefolderServiceUrl}/${id}`;
return this.http.delete<ITestcasefolder>(url, httpOptions)
.pipe(
  tap(_ => this.log(`deleted testcasefolder`)),
  catchError(this.handleError<ITestcasefolder>(`deletedTestcasefolder`))
);
}

 private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
   return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

     // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
     console.error(error); // log to console instead

     // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
     this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

     // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
     return of(result as T);
   };
 }
}
```

**itestcasefolder.ts:**

```ts
export class ITestcasefolder {
    id?: string;
    name?: string;
    description?: string;
    parentid?: string;
    children?: ITestcasefolder[];
}
```

Comment: Hello, Adnan! Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please paste your console output in the question (by editing your question)? Note that you should consider adding newlines where needed in your code for easier readability! Lastly, consider using _proper_ `PascalCase`: for example, `ITestcasefolder` should be `ITestCaseFolder`.

Comment: @AdnanCindioglu can u post answer bcoz i want to create dynamic tree view so help me for this